# DNS enable customers to resolve their domain to a page on my domain

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

I have a domain, site.com and want my customers to be able to resolve their domain to their page on my site -- for example customer.com will resolve to site.com/customers-page

Now I don't want the URL to read site.com/customers-page I want it to actually be their domain name. How would I accomplish this?

I am using an EC2 Amazon server. They have pointed their A record to my server ip address. But on my EC2 server what do I need to set up to ensure that customer.com will point to site.com/customers-page and the URL will read customer.com?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another option (which might be more easily maintainable if you have lots of customers) is to build the logic into your application.

You can read the host header from the request (I think that would be `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` in PHP) and determine which page to serve along with any other customer-specific behaviour.

However, you still have SSL to deal with. Since you're using AWS, you might want to consider using ELBs for that if the cost is not an issue. Then, the SSL termination becomes effectively a managed service.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this, although could present some scaling issues, is to create a reverse proxy to your site.

You would set up a virtual host which would proxy all requests upstream to your site. The exact configuration depends on which web server you are using, but should be fairly easy to set up.

If you need SSL, you will either have to add addtional IP addresses or use SNI.